# How can create a ListView Command with SPFx dynamically for several lists

Tags: spfx, pnp, pnp-js-core

I have created a **listview Command** for a specific list,
  "pageUrl": 
  "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/mySite/Lists/ListCommand/AllItems.aspx".

**It works fine**, but is it possible to create it dynamically in order to use it in other lists?

Answer (score 0):

My mistake, the page URL is for debugging and workbench, I deployed to app catalog and works fine for all the lists! sorry